# ASP.NET Core MVC : retrieve DateTime from database into view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm quite new to ASP.NET Core MVC and I'm having trouble retrieving a `DateTime` value from the database into the 'Edit' razor view.

I can use the scaffolded views to create a new Activity Item and this displays correctly in the 'Index' list, and in the 'Details' view, but when I attempt to 'Edit' the entry the DateTime value doesn't pull through from the database.

I've done plenty of reading but the main thing I seem to get in search results is information about JQuery Datepickers.

Any advice on where to look, how to resolve would be very much appreciated.

Here is my model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace MISDataRepo.Models
{
    [Table("Activity",Schema = "coir")]
    public partial class ActivityItem
    {
        public ActivityItem()
        {
            ActivityIdentifier = new HashSet<ActivityIdentifier>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int ActivityItemId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A valid Activity Name is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Activity Name")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string ActivityName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Activity Type")]
        public int ActivityTypeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Date Activity Created")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date Activity Modified")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? DatetModified { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Created By (Employee ID)")]
        [RegularExpression("^[1-9][0-9]{6}$", ErrorMessage = "A valid Employee ID is required!")]
        public int? CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Project Co-Ordinator (Employee ID)")]
        [RegularExpression("^[1-9][0-9]{6}$", ErrorMessage = "A valid Employee ID is required!")]
        public int? PC { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(true)]
        public bool Live { get; set; }

        public virtual ActivityType ActivityType { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ActivityIdentifier> ActivityIdentifier { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the view:

```
@model MISDataRepo.Models.ActivityItem

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>ActivityItem</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="ActivityItemId" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ActivityName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ActivityName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ActivityName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ActivityTypeId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ActivityTypeId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ActivityTypeId"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="ActivityTypeId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DateCreated" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Html.DisplayFor(a => a.DateCreated)" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DateCreated" class="text-danger"></span>
                @*<input type="hidden" asp-for="DateCreated"   type="date" placeholder="Enter Date Created" value="@Model.DateCreated" />*@
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DatetModified" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Html.DisplayFor(a => a.DatetModified)" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DatetModified" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CreatedBy" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CreatedBy" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CreatedBy" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PC" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PC" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PC" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Live" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Live)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Here are the 'Edit' methods of the controller

```
// GET: ActivityItems/Edit/5
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var activityItem = await _context.ActivityItem.FindAsync(id);

    if (activityItem == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    ViewData["ActivityTypeId"] = new SelectList(_context.ActivityType, "ActivityTypeId", "ActivityTypeName", activityItem.ActivityTypeId);
    return View(activityItem);
}

// POST: ActivityItems/Edit/5
// To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
//public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ActivityItemId,ActivityName,ActivityTypeId,DateCreated,DatetModified,CreatedBy,PC,Live")] ActivityItem activityItem)
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ActivityItemId,ActivityName,ActivityTypeId,DatetModified,CreatedBy,PC,Live")] ActivityItem activityItem)
{
    if (id != activityItem.ActivityItemId)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Update(activityItem);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!ActivityItemExists(activityItem.ActivityItemId))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    ViewData["ActivityTypeId"] = new SelectList(_context.ActivityType, "ActivityTypeId", "ActivityTypeName", activityItem.ActivityTypeId);

    return View(activityItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when I attempt to 'Edit' the entry the DateTime value doesn't pull
> through from the database.

Yes, the issue you are having with the your `View` is pretty obvious due to your `HTML Helper atrribute` that is `@Html.DisplayFor` and the `Property` you have defined within your `Model` `ActivityItem`. You are probably getting following issue.

**Problem:**

[image]

**How To Resolve:**

Either you could use `ViewModel` or you can redefine your property `public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }` by get rid of your annotations. However, I would prefer to use `ViewModel`. On the other hands, use the property like `asp-for="DateCreated"` within your `edit view` and get rid of your additional `HTML helper class` `@Html.DisplayFor`. Follow the below steps.

**View Model:**

```
public class ActivityItemViewModel
{

    public int ActivityItemId { get; set; }
    public string ActivityName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DatetModified { get; set; }
}
```

**Note:** While loading your `Edit` view you certainly doesn't require `annotations` so you can ommit that.

**View :**

In view you are using additional `HTML helper class` `@Html.DisplayFor` which is not required in this scenario. You could try as following:

```
@model DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.ActivityItemViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
   
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>ActivityItem</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="ActivityItemId" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ActivityName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ActivityName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ActivityName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DateCreated" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DateCreated" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DateCreated" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DatetModified" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DateCreated" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DatetModified" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-action="ActivityList">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Sure, let me know if any further assistance required.

Comment: Hi @Md Farid Uddin Kiron, the solution worked, however I need to have the date formatted as dd/MM/yyyy, as soon as I apply that formatting via the View then I get the same issue.
Is there any other way to add the formatting but ensure tnat the data pulls through from the Database when the View loads?

Comment: Yes this common issue, when you set `annotation` no longer it cannot interpret with view, because  in views `HTML helper`  treated as `string`, therefore, you should better use view model and cast the format when required.

Comment: Thank You.  So if I use ViewModel will this allow me to set the date format dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: Well, it can be a different investigation as we pointed to another goal tough. Moreover, could you post another question devpted to that  therefore, can be pondered over.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your input to this. I've now found a solution by using a Jquery datepicker.  Your help and information made this possible.

Comment: Glad to assist you therefore, thanks for the update.